# How to describe an optional negative lookahead in regular expression?

Tags: regex, grep, regex-lookarounds

I like to get the appointment description of calender entries which a program called khal outputs by using grep. The output of khal looks like this:

```
20:30-22:30 13.05.2015: Manfred treffen Repeat: FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=WE;WKST=MO
09.05. - 12.05.2015: Britt Besuch
```

In the example I would like to match `Manfred treffen` and `Britt Besuch`. However, as you can see the first appointment is a repeating appointment and there for khal adds these information to the output. In this case the regular expression has to assure that every the whole part starting with `Repeat:` will be omitted, but of course only if it exists.

`grep -oP "(?<=: )(.)+(?=Repeat: .+$)"` gets me
`Manfred treffen` but not `Britt Besuch`

However `grep -oP "(?<=: )(.)+(?=Repeat: .+$|$)"` gives me descriptions of both appointments but the first one with the whole "Repeat:…" part included.

What I seem to need is an optional lookahead. I found a similar question on stackoverflow but didn't really understand the approach (Greedy match) nor was it possible to adopt it for my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one

```
(?<=\d{4}:).+?(?=Repeat|$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zB7tM6/1)

Answer (score 3):

To cut the match at `Repeat:` use this lookbehind:

```
(?<=: )(.+)(?= Repeat:|$)
```

Rather than matching everything starting at `Repeat:` to the end, match only `Repeat:`, with a space in front of it. In other words, remove the `.+$` from your lookbehind. This is enough to stop the match after the name, producing the result that you expect.

ie,

```
grep -oP '(?<=: ).+(?= Repeat:|$)' file
```

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/fL1hV4/1)

Comment: You don't need to go for capturing group.

Comment: This will match `Britt Besuch this is a sentence` within `09.05. - 12.05.2015: Britt Besuch this is a sentence`

Comment: strange, in the demo it works. On my computer however I still get all the "Repeat: " information string up to the end

Comment: @dasblinkenlight this is not going to work if you add other lines , it works only for two lines because the second line is considered to be at the end of string

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add the `repeat` in your regex all you need is a capture group after a date with `:`

```
\d+\.\d+\.\d+:\s?(\w+ \w+)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bN7xF8/1)

But if you just want to use `:` and you just want the names and the names are 2 part you can use the following regex :

```
(?<=: )[a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+
```

If you dont know the length of name after `:` you can use the following regex :

```
\d+\.\d+\.\d+:\s?(.+)((?= \w+:)|$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bN7xF8/2)

Comment: Ok this works for this example. I should have added that appointment descriptions might vary in length and shape of cause. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

```
(?m)(?<=(?<!Repeat): ).*?(?=Repeat|$)
```

You can try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/mT0iE7/19

Comment: This regex gives me no result at all, allthough I understand the idea to exclude "Repeat" from the appearance of the first ":"

Comment: @CutúChiqueño you are using it with `grep -P` right?it would be `grep -P "(?m)(?<=(?<!Repeat): ).*?(?=Repeat|$)"`